# Writing a raw audio to a file?

Tags: c, audio, libvlc, libsndfile

I'm writing a piece of code in C for `pocketsphinx` module of `freeswitch` to save the utterance (waveform or audio) to a file. I receive the audio as a `void *data` and its `unsigned int len` and I have to save it as a `RAW` (or `PCM`) file (no headers).
How do I do this?

I've tried this:

```
FILE *_file;
int16_t *_data;
_data = (int16_t *) data;
_file=fopen("utterance","ab");
fwrite(data, sizeof(_data[0]), sizeof(_data)/sizeof(_data[0]), _file);
fclose(_file);
_file=NULL;
```

It doesn't work (Maybe I'm not doing it right?). I've also found `libvlc` and `libsndfile` but haven't found any function that'd serve me.
Anyone here have a simple example/tutorial on this?

I'm working on C, VS2010, Win8.1 (x64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't use `sizeof(_data)/sizeof(_data[0])` when _data is a pointer; `sizeof(_data)` is how many bytes the pointer `_data` takes

```
size_t valueCount = sampleCount * channelCount;
FILE *_file;
int16_t *_data;
_data = (int16_t *) data;
_file=fopen("utterance","ab");
fwrite(data, sizeof(_data[0]), valueCount, _file);
fclose(_file);
_file=NULL;
```

you could also use

```
fwrite(data, 1, len, _file);
```

Comment: I can't believe how I missed that. I used `fwrite(data, 1, len, _file);` and it's working. Thanks a ton Jake, for fast and accurate reply!

Answer (score 0):

The major issue with this is that you use `sizeof(_data) / sizeof(_data[0])` as an attempt to compute the length of the array. However, since `_data` is of type `int16_t *`, i.e. just a pointer, then `sizeof(_data)` will return the size of a pointer (which, in your case, is just 8). You'll need some other way to pass in the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` applied to a pointer does not tell you how much memory there is "behind it" (the pointer doesn't know whether it's pointing at one lonely thing, or at the first element of an array).
Instead it tells you the size, measured in `char`s, of a pointer, which is usually 4 or 8 these days.

Since you know where the data is (`data`) and how much there is of it (`len`), you don't need to cast or calculate anything.

Use either

```
fwrite(data, 1, len, _file);
```

or

```
fwrite(data, len, 1, _file);
```